# How do I push my initial snapshot to a subscriber server in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: replication, sql-server

I'm configuring Transactional Replication using the Push model. The scenario is:

The SQL Servers:

- SQL01 (publisher) and SQL02 (subscriber) - both running SQL 2000 SP4.
- Both servers are standalone (i.e. not domain members)
- Both servers have their FQDN and NETBIOS names in their HOSTS files

I've managed to configure SQL01 to publish my database and configured a Push subscription for SQL02 using the *Push New Subscription* wizard and set the Distribution Agent to update the subscription continuously.

On the Push Subscription wizard *"Initialise Subscription"* page I've selected *"Yes, initialise the schema and data"* and ticked the *"Start the Snapshot Agent to begin the initialisation process immediately"* option.

All the required services are running (SQL Agent).

When I complete the wizard and browse the Replication -> Publications folder I can see my publication (blue book with arrow). The publication shows the Push subscription and its status is *Pending*.

If I look in the `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Mssql\Repldata` folder I see a number of T-SQL scripts for each table e.g.  `Products.bcp, Products.sch, Products.idx`.

What should happen now? Should my replicated database now (magically) appear on the subscription server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working, didn't realise I had to create an empty database on the subscriber server first. The SQL 2000 Books Online documentation isn't very clear about that.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show me how you configured that HOSTS file? just use "foo" names, I just need to see how you specified what.

I made mine by using "client network" configuration and then ALIAS... dont know if that the reason for my current problem with setting these up.